# How can I see a list of all my shared folders?

Tags: shared-folders

Sometimes I find directories that I left shared a long time ago but forgot to un-share. Is there a way to see a list of all my shared folders so I can remove folders that I no longer need to be shared? I'm using Maverick Meerkat.